# Electric Heat Thermostat Wiring

Tags: electrical, thermostat

I am trying to wire a new thermostat, unfortunately i neglected to take a picture of the old wiring. I believe I have an understanding of how it needs to be wires but i could use a second opinion. Can you please help?

I suspect this is what they are calling for but would like confirmation:

L1 to 4

T1 to 2

L2 to 3

T2 to 1

The thermostat is a CT410B Non Programmable Electric Thermostat.

The wires shown below with the wire nuts are the wires from the breaker. The ones without caps are to the heating source (baseboard heat).

[image]

Here is the wiring diagram.

[image]

And lastly the back of the thermostat:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That will work.

It actually does not matter "which of 3,4 connects to L1, L2" nor "which of 1,2 connects to T1, T2", but conventionally you would like to keep the same color on the same side.

*i.e.* L1 -> 3 and L2 -> 4 works no worse nor better than what you had - in 240V single phase the lines are interchangeable.

It's also polite to put red or black tape or paint on the white wires, but normally considered "obvious" in this application.

Answer (score 0):

So your blacks hook up to the blacks on the thermostat
The whites to the red wires of the thermostat
The hot black to L1 the hot white to L2
You would not have confused your self if you would have labeled L1 hot as black and L2 as hot white
L= line or mains supply
T= load of your heater